# Google Calendar Events inserted using api not printing

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Events inserted using google's api and service account shows up fine when I view the calendar, but they are not included when I print the calendar.

Events manually inserted are printed as expected. I am using the following code.

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar };
GoogleCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream("mikeServiceAccount.json", FileMode.Open, 
  FileAccess.Read))
{
    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(scopes);
}

// Create the Calendar service.
var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "Calendar Authentication Sample",
});

Event myEvent = new Event
{
    Summary = "Summary Title",
    Description = "event description"
    Location = "Nashville, TN"
    Start = new EventDateTime()
            {
                Date = "2018-10-19"
            },
            End = new EventDateTime()
            {
                Date = "2018-10-19"
            }
}; 
service.Events.Insert(myEvent,"b4sbsrsdf9r82sbj0@group.calendar.google.com").Execute();
```

Here is a composite screen shot of what I see when I view and print the calendar. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FqAk.png

Comment: What do you mean by print the calendar?

Comment: I see all events just viewing the calendare, but when I hit ctrl-p I only see events manually added in the print preview screen. I have screen shots. Let me see if I can add them to my question. Thanks!

Comment: please include your print screen code then

Comment: The c# code used is what I included in my initial post. Here's the link to the screen shot itself.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FqAk.png

Comment: The code you have posted dosent include anything for printing.

Comment: I experience the events added via api hiding when I manually try to print the calendar. Do I need to set something in the code to allow printing?

Comment: Any update on this? I have exactly the same issue with a Chrome Extension that successfully creates events, but which do not show when printing, even after logging out/in. The events are otherwise completely normal, and can be synced, edited etc with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work this out, but it was really just ended up being a proof of concept, so I don't have code I look back on. As I remember it the problem ended up being the value I used as my endDate. I don't remember specifics, but maybe I used the same date as the startDate and added the end time of midnight. Something like that anyway. Good luck and sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Using the information provided by mikeh as a hint,

we were able to resolve the issue "All-day events are not displayed when printing".

The solution in my case by...

setting the start to "YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00" and...

setting the end to 00:00:00 on the "next day" of the start.

Thank you.

```
start: {
  dateTime : new Date("2020-01-25T00:00:00").toISOString()
  ,timeZone: 'Asia/Tokyo'
}
,end: {
  dateTime : new Date("2020-01-26T00:00:00").toISOString()
  ,timeZone: 'Asia/Tokyo'
}
```